# Having trouble connecting to Apache OpenMeetings through Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, openmeetings

I've installed OpenMeetings v5.0.0 on my server and was able to configure and log in using ssh tunnel.

So I set up an Nginx reverse proxy as described in this tutorial:

https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-openmeetings-on-ubuntu-16-04

When I enter the URL in my browser, it redirects to https://myhost/openmeetings/signin and displays the login page, but these two AJAX calls get a '400 - Bad Request' response:

https://myhost/openmeetings/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.openmeetings.web.pages.auth.SignInPage?7-1.0-&&_=1586132831523

https://myhost/openmeetings/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.openmeetings.web.pages.auth.SignInPage?7-1.0-signin&navigatorAppName=Netscape&navigatorAppVersion=5.0%20(X11)&navigatorAppCodeName=Mozilla&navigatorCookieEnabled=true&navigatorJavaEnabled=false&navigatorLanguage=en-CA&navigatorPlatform=Linux%20x86_64&navigatorUserAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(X11%3B%20Ubuntu%3B%20Linux%20x86_64%3B%20rv%3A74.0)%20Gecko%2F20100101%20Firefox%2F74.0&screenWidth=1680&screenHeight=1050&screenColorDepth=24&utcOffset=-8&utcDSTOffset=-7&browserWidth=1680&browserHeight=619&hostname=myhost&codebase=https%3A%2F%2Fmyhost%2Fopenmeetings%2Fsignin&settings=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&_=1586132831524

And when I hit the 'Sign In' button, another '400 - Bad Request'

My Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    gzip off;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhost/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhost/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    server_name                   www.myhost myhost;

    access_log                    /var/log/nginx/myserver.access.log;
    error_log                     /var/log/nginx/myhost.error.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass            http://localhost:5080;
            proxy_set_header    host $host;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header connection "upgrade";
        }
}

server {
    if ($host = www.myhost) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = myhost) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;

    server_name                   www.myhost myhost;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

As per the tutorial, I have tried changing the application.base.url setting to https://myhost. It makes no difference.

Comment: This one has been reported as working config: https://markmail.org/message/4embi7g4jbvl46j2

Answer (score 0):

I would include a .com or anything in hosts and in my web url

You need to rename a folder in /opt/open504
Also make a change in server.xml of openmeetings. 
Make changes in configurations. restart the application or best your entire server machine.

Let me know if video and audio works. Connect from an external source and not from your own router(lan).